# I write analyze function to return count of token

Tags: python, dictionary, tokenize, init, stringtokenizer

I  write analyze function to return count of token

```
def analyze(self, text):
    tokenizer = nltk.tokenize.TweetTokenizer()

    with open(text, 'r') as lines:
        tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(str(lines))
        score = 0

        for token in tokens:
            if token.lower() in self.negatives:
                score -= 1
            elif token.lower() in self.positives:
                score += 1
    return score
```

Call:

```
print(search.analyze('cat.txt'))
```

Output:
0

Comment: Thanks, Kallz for fixing the code! Now it works perfectly. The problem was in the position of the return function. Initially, it was inside the for loop and it returned score for the first line only.

Answer (score -1):

There is too little information about the functions and the file.

Try debugging your code. For example, print each token and its score (+1 or -1) and see how the model works.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Thank you, I will try the method